# angular-shepherd Tour Guide is not scrolling on clicking next page

Tags: html, css, angular6

Everything is working fine except scrolling when i click to the next element is taking their but is not scrolling to down for seeing purpose I have to scroll to down. I tried many ways but i could not able to fix please help me to fix this problem i gone through this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-shepherd but no option . If anyone can help me that would be very great help for me.

```
<h2 class="second-element">London</h2>

<p class="third-element">London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>

<div class="first-element">cool</div>
```

I have added this in my app.component.ts file code..

```
import { ShepherdService } from 'angular-shepherd';


export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private shepherdService: ShepherdService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.shepherdService.disableScroll = true;
    this.shepherdService.modal = true;
    this.shepherdService.confirmCancel = false;
    this.shepherdService.addSteps([
      {
        id: 'intro',
        options: {
          attachTo: '.first-element bottom',
          beforeShowPromise: function() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                resolve();
              }, 500);
            });
          },
          buttons: [
            {
              classes: 'shepherd-button-secondary',
              text: 'Exit',
              type: 'cancel'
            },
            {
              classes: 'shepherd-button-primary',
              text: 'Back',
              type: 'back'
            },
            {
              classes: 'shepherd-button-primary',
              text: 'Next',
              type: 'next'
            }
          ],
          classes: 'custom-class-name-1 custom-class-name-2',
          highlightClass: 'highlight',
          scrollTo: true,
          showCancelLink: true,
          title: 'Welcome to Rivet Labs',
          text: ['This will help you toggle sidebar menu'],
          when: {
            show: () => {
              console.log('show step');
            },
            hide: () => {
              console.log('hide step');
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
      here is 2nd id goes here 
      },
      {
      here is 3rd id goes here
      }
}
```

Comment: Isn't your this causing problem?  ` this.shepherdService.disableScroll = true;` it should be false I guess

Answer (score 0):

I have solve my problem just we need to remove scroll function from next id to get to the element in default position. we have to remove this property  //beforeShowPromise:function(){}// for next id.

```
     beforeShowPromise: function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            resolve();
          }, 500);
        });
      },
```